# Xpages Calendar Date range

Tags: rest, xpages

I have used the REST service and INotes Calendar from a TeaRoom database to get a view to feed a Calendar which is great!
Although I want to add entries to this calendar which are feed from two different date fields on the same document.

Basically show a Fabrication Date as well as a Delivery Date, which I can get to display as separate entries in a view (easy) but the REST service seems to remove the second date (probably based on the UNID?)

I would also like to have the manufacturing date spread across a date range - so this will take 3 days to make for example and display this on the calendar too.

Any ideas or help would be really appreciated.

Many thanks

Andrew